# extract tagged entities from within <p> elements

Tags: java, jsoup

My dataset has the following structure:

```
<p>The <ORGANIZATION>Peter Hall Company</ORGANIZATION>'s production of ''Blithe Spirit,'' directed by <PERSON>Thea Sharrock</PERSON>, is one of those attractively and unimaginatively upholstered productions of brittle classics that become must-have middlebrow tickets every few years. Most notable for <PERSON>Penelope Keith</PERSON>'s startlingly brisk and no-nonsense interpretation of the madcap medium <ORGANIZATION>Madame Arcati</ORGANIZATION>, Ms. <PERSON>Sharrock</PERSON>'s take on <PERSON>Coward</PERSON>'s 1941 comedy of a man visited by his dead wife's impish spirit delivers bright badinage, dazed double takes and marital melees at the same efficient clip.</p>
```

As you can see, within the tags `<p>` & `</p>` there are multiple tagged entities, such as `<ORGANIZATION>Peter Hall Company</ORGANIZATION>` and `<PERSON>Penelope Keith</PERSON>`

Using jsoup I'd like to list out all  of those entities contained within `<p>` tags.

I guess jsoup should be able to handle that, I've seen some questions that are related to specific instances of this but I've not been able to make them work in my case, could this be becasue `<ORGANIZATION>` and `<PERSON>` are not real html tags? do I have to use regex for those? If I can do it with jsoup, how?

I tried this so far:

```
    for (Iterator<Element> iterator = contents.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Element content = iterator.next();
        String text = content.text();
        String title = content.select("PERSON").text();
        String output = text.replaceFirst(title, "").trim();
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

and this:

```
    for (Element content : contents) 
    {
        String PERSON = content.attr("PERSON");
        String linkText = content.text();

        //print
        System.out.println(PERSON);
        System.out.println(linkText);
    }
```

neither of which worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a css selector for that:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String xml = "<p>The <ORGANIZATION>Peter Hall Company</ORGANIZATION>'s production of ''Blithe Spirit,'' directed by <PERSON>Thea Sharrock</PERSON>, is one of those attractively and unimaginatively upholstered productions of brittle classics that become must-have middlebrow tickets every few years. Most notable for <PERSON>Penelope Keith</PERSON>'s startlingly brisk and no-nonsense interpretation of the madcap medium <ORGANIZATION>Madame Arcati</ORGANIZATION>, Ms. <PERSON>Sharrock</PERSON>'s take on <PERSON>Coward</PERSON>'s 1941 comedy of a man visited by his dead wife's impish spirit delivers bright badinage, dazed double takes and marital melees at the same efficient clip.</p>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);

        for (Element e: doc.select("p > ORGANIZATION, p > PERSON")) {
            System.out.printf("-> %s: %s\n", e.tagName(), e.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
-> organization: Peter Hall Company
-> person: Thea Sharrock
-> person: Penelope Keith
-> organization: Madame Arcati
-> person: Sharrock
-> person: Coward
```

Edit: If you want to filter-out these tags and just keep the contents you can replace the elements with their text content as you iterate over them, like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String xml = "<p>The <ORGANIZATION>Peter Hall Company</ORGANIZATION>'s production of ''Blithe Spirit,'' directed by <PERSON>Thea Sharrock</PERSON>, is one of those attractively and unimaginatively upholstered productions of brittle classics that become must-have middlebrow tickets every few years. Most notable for <PERSON>Penelope Keith</PERSON>'s startlingly brisk and no-nonsense interpretation of the madcap medium <ORGANIZATION>Madame Arcati</ORGANIZATION>, Ms. <PERSON>Sharrock</PERSON>'s take on <PERSON>Coward</PERSON>'s 1941 comedy of a man visited by his dead wife's impish spirit delivers bright badinage, dazed double takes and marital melees at the same efficient clip.</p>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);

        for (Element e: doc.select("p > ORGANIZATION, p > PERSON")) {
            System.out.printf("-> %s: %s\n", e.tagName(), e.text());
            e.replaceWith(new TextNode(e.text(), ""));
        }

        System.out.println("\nFiltered out:\n" + doc.select("p").html());
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
-> organization: Peter Hall Company
-> person: Thea Sharrock
-> person: Penelope Keith
-> organization: Madame Arcati
-> person: Sharrock
-> person: Coward

Filtered out:
The Peter Hall Company's production of ''Blithe Spirit,'' directed by Thea Sharrock, is one of those attractively and unimaginatively upholstered productions of brittle classics that become must-have middlebrow tickets every few years. Most notable for Penelope Keith's startlingly brisk and no-nonsense interpretation of the madcap medium Madame Arcati, Ms. Sharrock's take on Coward's 1941 comedy of a man visited by his dead wife's impish spirit delivers bright badinage, dazed double takes and marital melees at the same efficient clip.
```

Answer (score 0):

this works, but is inelegant

```
            //people
            Elements contents_person = doc.getElementsByTag("p").select("PERSON");

            for (Element content : contents_person) 
            {
                //String PERSON = content.attr("PERSON");
                String linkText = content.text();

                //print
                //System.out.println(PERSON);
                System.out.println(linkText);
            }

            //places
            Elements contents_place = doc.getElementsByTag("p").select("LOCATION");

            for (Element content : contents_place) 
            {
                //String PERSON = content.attr("PERSON");
                String linkText = content.text();

                //print
                //System.out.println(PERSON);
                System.out.println(linkText);
            }

            //things
            Elements contents_things = doc.getElementsByTag("p").select("ORGANIZATION");

            for (Element content : contents_things) 
            {
                //String PERSON = content.attr("PERSON");
                String linkText = content.text();

                //print
                //System.out.println(PERSON);
                System.out.println(linkText);
            }
```